# Can't start oracle DB on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I'm trying to make an application with Ruby on Rails using Oracle DB. After I set up the *'database.yml'* file, I tried to type `rake db:create`. 
but I got this message below:

> Rake tasks not supported by 'oracle_enhanced' adapter
>   Couldn't create database for {*"adapter"=>"oracle_enhanced", "database"=>"xx.xxx.xx.xx:1521/xxxx", "username"=>"****", "password"=>"****"*}
>   db/test.sqlite3 already exists
>   rake aborted!
>   LoadError: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql','mysql2','postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

I already installed `oracle_enhanced_adapter`, I don't understand what is the problem.

---

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~>5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>=1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~>4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~>2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~>0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug'
gem 'web-console', '~>2.0'
gem 'spring'
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'googlecharts'
gem 'rack'
```

Comment: contents of your Gem-file is useful too.

Comment: Post o/p of `bundle show oracle_enhanced_adapter`

Comment: it says 'Could not find gem 'oracle_enhanced_adapter'. but i already installed gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.2'

Comment: @MinjeongKim Please add content of your `Gemfile` to your question

Comment: just attached gemfile below. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Question is too old but it seems like the gem `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` is just missing from Gemfile so apparently it can't be loaded.

So apparently it has to be added.